# Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Conflict found: Field DayOfWeek 6 differs from DayOfWeek 2 derived from 2016-01-30

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, datetime-format

I am parsing dates like this: `"Sat, 30 Jan 2016 00:03:00 +0300"`

**But in some of the dates** it throw me this exception:

```
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Conflict found: Field DayOfWeek 6 differs from DayOfWeek 2 derived from 2016-01-30
```

or this:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Tue, 30 Jan 2016 00:06:00 +0300' could not be parsed: Conflict found: Field DayOfWeek 6 differs from DayOfWeek 2 derived from 2016-01-30
```

Here is some of my code:

```
DateTimeFormatter newformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);

OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( date , newformatter );
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```

Input for example that throws exception:

```
Input:"Tue, 30 Jan 2016 00:06:00 +0300"
exception: "Text 'Tue, 30 Jan 2016 00:06:00 +0300' could not be parsed: Conflict found: Field DayOfWeek 6 differs from DayOfWeek 2 derived from 2016-01-30"
```

Comment: We need the input. The input is important since your dates may not be entirely correct concerning the day of the week.

Comment: I edited and add my input and the exception for this input

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is simply because 30 Jan 2016 is Saturday and not Tuesday.